# Microsoft Azure pipeline setup to build android APK and push it to Appcenter

Tags: android, azure, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have been working on this and my current Yaml pipeline script looks like this:

```
 variables:
- group: configurationAppCenterAppSlug
- group: configurationPipeline


parameters:
  - name: schemeName
    displayName: 'Choose environment:'
    type: string
    default: stageCasa
    values:
      - stageCasa
      - stageCz
      - stagePsk
      - stageSk
      - stageRo

trigger:
- casa-redesign

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'


steps:

- checkout: self
  displayName: 'Update repo files'
  fetchDepth: 1
  fetchTags: false
  lfs: false
  clean: false

- script: |
    echo "Checking for Java 11"
    if /usr/libexec/java_home -v 11 >/dev/null 2>&1; then
      echo "Java 11 found"
      JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11)
      echo "Setting JAVA_HOME to $JAVA_HOME"
    else
      echo "Java 11 not found, installing via Homebrew"
      brew install openjdk@11
      brew link --force --overwrite openjdk@11
      JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11)
      echo "Setting JAVA_HOME to $JAVA_HOME"
    fi
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=JAVA_HOME]$JAVA_HOME"
  displayName: 'Check for Java 11 and install if not present'

- script: |
    echo "JAVA_HOME is set to: $JAVA_HOME"
    java -version
  displayName: 'Verify Java Installation'

- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: "bundle${{ parameters.schemeName }}Release"
  env:
    JAVA_HOME: $(JAVA_HOME)


    
- script: |
    if [ -f "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/app/build/outputs/bundle/stageCasaRelease/app-stage-casa-release.aab" ]; then
      cp "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/app/build/outputs/bundle/stageCasaRelease/app-stage-casa-release.aab" "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app-stage-casa-release.aab"
      echo "AAB file copied successfully."
    else
      echo "AAB file does not exist."
    fi
  displayName: 'Copy AAB file to Artifact Staging Directory'
  

- task: AppCenterDistribute@3
  inputs:
    serverEndpoint: 'AppCenter Service'
    # appSlug: 'FEG/Vegas-CASA-Stage-1'
    appSlug: '$(${{ parameters.schemeName }}_appSlug)'
    appFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app-stage-casa-release.aab'
    releaseNotesOption: 'input'
    releaseNotesInput: '- empty'
```

What bothers me is that when I run this pipeline, it sometimes works. It builds aab file and pushes it to the Appcenter.
Other times it fails with errors like this:

```
    AppCenterDistribute

View raw log

Starting: AppCenterDistribute
==============================================================================
Task         : App Center distribute
Description  : Distribute app builds to testers and users via Visual Studio App Center
Version      : 3.232.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/app-center-distribute
==============================================================================
##[error]Error: Cannot find any file based on /Users/runner/work/1/a/app-stage-casa-release.aab.
Finishing: AppCenterDistribute
```

It confuses me because sometimes it works and sometimes not. Where am I going wrong here are there any ideas. I feel like I'm very close to the solution, it's like 1 piece of puzzle is missing... Thanks

Comment: According to the error message, it cannot find your AAB file. Add a command before the "AppCenterDistribute@3" task to list the contents in `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` and check whether the target AAB file is copied successfully. If it has been copied, add a variable `system.debug` and set the value to `true` in your pipeline. Compare the debug logs of the successful build with the failed build to see if there are any differences.

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT it obviously sometimes finds aab file there and sometimes does not. I don't understand this behaviour of gradle build process. Shouldn't it put aab file every time on same place?

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT is it maybe possible that gradle sometimes does not have enough time to build aab file and put it to the directory and before it is finished, the copy command try to copy it and it fails..?

Comment: 1. "is it maybe possible that gradle sometimes does not have enough time to build aab file and put it to the directory and before it is finished," - You can check whether the aab file is generated and the path where it is stored in the debug log of `Gradle@2` task.  2. To narrow down the issue, add a command before "AppCenterDistribute@3" task to list the contents in `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` and check whether the target AAB file is successfully copied. 3. Afterwards we can know whether the AAB file was not successfully generated or the path was changed, or the copy was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **@Ziyang Liu-MSFT** for your comments.

You can use the ***Azure Yaml pipeline*** below which utilizes **`if else statements`** to check if the *AAB files exist or not*:-

```yaml
variables:
- group: configurationAppCenterAppSlug
- group: configurationPipeline

parameters:
  - name: schemeName
    displayName: 'Choose environment:'
    type: string
    default: stageCasa
    values:
      - stageCasa
      - stageCz
      - stagePsk
      - stageSk
      - stageRo

trigger:
- casa-redesign

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

steps:
- checkout: self
  displayName: 'Update repo files'
  fetchDepth: 1
  fetchTags: false
  lfs: false
  clean: false

- script: |
    echo "Checking for Java 11"
    if /usr/libexec/java_home -v 11 >/dev/null 2>&1; then
      echo "Java 11 found"
      JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11)
      echo "Setting JAVA_HOME to $JAVA_HOME"
    else
      echo "Java 11 not found, installing via Homebrew"
      brew install openjdk@11
      brew link --force --overwrite openjdk@11
      JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11)
      echo "Setting JAVA_HOME to $JAVA_HOME"
    fi
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=JAVA_HOME]$JAVA_HOME"
  displayName: 'Check for Java 11 and install if not present'

- script: |
    echo "JAVA_HOME is set to: $JAVA_HOME"
    java -version
  displayName: 'Verify Java Installation'

- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: "bundle${{ parameters.schemeName }}Release"
  env:
    JAVA_HOME: $(JAVA_HOME)

- script: |
    if [ -f "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/app/build/outputs/bundle/${{ parameters.schemeName }}Release/app-${{ parameters.schemeName }}-release.aab" ]; then
      cp "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/app/build/outputs/bundle/${{ parameters.schemeName }}Release/app-${{ parameters.schemeName }}-release.aab" "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app-${{ parameters.schemeName }}-release.aab"
      echo "AAB file copied successfully."
    else
      echo "AAB file does not exist."
      exit 1
    fi
  displayName: 'Copy AAB file to Artifact Staging Directory'

- task: AppCenterDistribute@3
  inputs:
    serverEndpoint: 'AppCenter Service'
    appSlug: '$(appSlug)'  # Make sure the correct variable name is used here
    appFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app-${{ parameters.schemeName }}-release.aab'
    releaseNotesOption: 'input'
    releaseNotesInput: '- empty'
```